# importing package and modules from another directory in python

Tags: python, package

I have a bunch of python scripts in the path

```
/home/yotam/Applications/pyFoo
```

one of them is `__init__.py` which, to my understanding, turns the `pyFoo` folder into a package. The folder also has a `src` subfolder, which stores an `__init__.py` file of its own, as well as some other helpful scripts.

I want to import one of the files (modules?), called `Bar.py`, that uses scripts from `/home/yotam/Applications/pyFoo/src`. If I try to load it from the python interpreter, while in the folder ''/home/yotam/Applications'' using

```
>>> from pyFoo import Bar as B
```

everything is fine. If, however I want to run it from other folders, e.g. my home directory, I get the error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

How can I import `Bar.py` from anyplace on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the directory to your `sys.path`:

```python
import sys
sys.path.append( '/path/to/libs' )

import my_lib_in_another_dir
```